# Display another field in many2one instead of name

Tags: odoo

I have a many2one field like this

```
'product_id': fields.many2one('product.product', 'Product', required=True)
```

It displays me all the product names (name attribute from product_template class) and stores id inside. I would like to display the part_number of the product instead of name and store id inside. Is there a way to do this in openerp7. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You just use _rec_name = 'part_number' in your product_template class, so it will set your default attribute as 'part_number' instead of 'name' while using many2one

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

The name that is displayed for relational fields is the result of the `name_get` method.  You can inherit `product.product` and override `name_get` but that will affect the entire system, every time a product is displayed it will change this.  You could code around this using the `context` but it is starting to get messy.

If you just want the code I would create a related field like this.

```
'product_ref': fields.related(
        'product_id',
        'part_number',
        string='Product',
        readonly=True,
        type='char',
        help = 'The product part number',
        )
```

and then use this on your form.  The ORM layer is smart enough that if your particular record doesn't have a product ID or a product doesn't have a part number it will handle it gracefully.

If you needed to be a little trickier you could create a functional field that showed say the name and the part number for example.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, It was really good and useful. However my intention is to search the part no from the existing product list (instead of name, want to search by part no). If i specify a many2one field i can type the first few letters of the name and the products names that matches will be dropped down, in my case i would require to search by part no. Hope i've explained my need clearly. Kindly give me some suggestions to implement that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My basic intention was to display Part-Number of the product for all products and give ability to search by Part-Number.

I accomplished it this way in **product.product** class,(Code between #Vivek and #End are my code snippets)

```
def name_get(self, cr, user, ids, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    if isinstance(ids, (int, long)):
        ids = [ids]
    if not len(ids):
        return []
    def _name_get(d):
        name = d.get('name','')
        code = d.get('default_code',False)
        # Vivek
        part_number = d.get('part_number',False)
        if part_number:
            name = '%s-%s' % (name,part_number)
        #End
        elif code:
            name = '[%s] %s' % (code,name)
        elif d.get('variants'):
            name = name + ' - %s' % (d['variants'],)
        return (d['id'], name)

    partner_id = context.get('partner_id', False)

    result = []
    for product in self.browse(cr, user, ids, context=context):
        sellers = filter(lambda x: x.name.id == partner_id, product.seller_ids)
        # Vivek
        prd_temp = self.pool.get('product.template').browse(cr, user, product.id, context=context)
        # End
        if sellers:
            for s in sellers:
                mydict = {
                          'id': product.id,
                          'name': s.product_name or product.name,
                          #vivek
                          'part_number': prd_temp.part_number,
                          #End
                          'default_code': s.product_code or product.default_code,
                          'variants': product.variants
                          }
                result.append(_name_get(mydict))
        else:
            mydict = {
                      'id': product.id,
                      'name': product.name,
                      #vivek
                      'part_number': prd_temp.part_number,
                      #End
                      'default_code': product.default_code,
                      'variants': product.variants
                      }
            result.append(_name_get(mydict))
    return result

def name_search(self, cr, user, name='', args=None, operator='ilike', context=None, limit=100):
    if not args:
        args = []
    if name:
        ids = self.search(cr, user, [('default_code','=',name)]+ args, limit=limit, context=context)
        if not ids:
            ids = self.search(cr, user, [('ean13','=',name)]+ args, limit=limit, context=context)
        if not ids:
            # Do not merge the 2 next lines into one single search, SQL search performance would be abysmal
            # on a database with thousands of matching products, due to the huge merge+unique needed for the
            # OR operator (and given the fact that the 'name' lookup results come from the ir.translation table
            # Performing a quick memory merge of ids in Python will give much better performance
            ids = set()
            ids.update(self.search(cr, user, args + [('default_code',operator,name)], limit=limit, context=context))
            if not limit or len(ids) < limit:
                # we may underrun the limit because of dupes in the results, that's fine
                ids.update(self.search(cr, user, args + [('name',operator,name)], limit=(limit and (limit-len(ids)) or False) , context=context))
                # vivek
                # Purpose  : To filter the product by using part_number
                ids.update(self.search(cr, user, args + [('part_number',operator,name)], limit=(limit and (limit-len(ids)) or False) , context=context))
                #End
            ids = list(ids)
        if not ids:
            ptrn = re.compile('(\[(.*?)\])')
            res = ptrn.search(name)
            if res:
                ids = self.search(cr, user, [('default_code','=', res.group(2))] + args, limit=limit, context=context)
    else:
        ids = self.search(cr, user, args, limit=limit, context=context)
    result = self.name_get(cr, user, ids, context=context)
    return result
```

But the problem with this particular functionality is "It's a global change" wherever you get to list the products the display will be **Product Name - Part Number**. If someone can do that better for context specific actions it will be great.

Further answers are eagerly welcome. :)

Answer (score -2):

when you use the browse method, you get all information data of product.

if you get properties use:

```
<yourobject>.product_id.name
<yourobject>.product_id.default_code
<yourobject>.product_id.type
<yourobject>.product_id.<your_property>
```

I hope you use. regards